# Full Calendar dayGridMonth not showing dot and time format

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, time-format, fullcalendar-6

I want to display time format before event. Something like "8p - Event" in the month view.

[image]

I am using fullcalendar 4 with symfony 6!
This i have so far
[image]
Thanks in advance!

This is my calendar code with Calendar Bundle
https://github.com/tattali/CalendarBundle

```
`<?php

public function __construct(EventRepository $eventRepository, UrlGeneratorInterface $router, ConfigDataService $configDataService) {
    $this->eventRepository = $eventRepository;
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->configDataService = $configDataService;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        CalendarEvents::SET_DATA => 'onCalendarSetData',
    ];
}

public function onCalendarSetData(CalendarEvent $calendar)
{
    $start = $calendar->getStart();
    $end = $calendar->getEnd();
    $filters = $calendar->getFilters();

    $service = $this->eventRepository->getCountEventsByService('active');

    $eventsRepository = $this->eventRepository->findEventsNotCancelled('cancelled');
    //dd($eventsRepository);
    foreach ($eventsRepository as $eventRepository) {
        if(!empty($eventRepository->getClient()->getFirstName()) || !empty($eventRepository->getClient()->getLastName())) {
            $name = $eventRepository->getClient()->getFirstName() . ' ' . $eventRepository->getClient()->getLastName();
        } else {
            $name = $eventRepository->getClient()->getEmail();
        }
        if($this->configDataService->get('eventByTime') == 'YES' && $eventRepository->getEventTime() != null) {
            $startTime = $eventRepository->getEventTime();
            $endTime = $eventRepository->getEventTimeEnd();
            if($startTime != null) {
                $eventStartDate = new \DateTime($eventRepository->getEventDate()->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' .$startTime->format('H:i:s'));
                //$eventStartDate = $eventRepository->getEventDate()->modify($startTime->format('H:i:s'));
                //$eventStartDate = $startTime->
            } else {
                $eventStartDate = null;
            }
            if($endTime != null) {
                $eventEndDate = new \DateTime($eventRepository->getEventDate()->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' .$endTime->format('H:i:s'));
            } else {
                $eventEndDate = null;
            }

            $calendarEvent = new Event(
                $name . ' Status: ' . ucfirst($eventRepository->getStatus()),
                $eventStartDate,
                $eventEndDate,
            );
        } else {
            //dd($eventRepository->getEventDate());
            $eventStartDate = $eventRepository->getEventDate();
            $eventEndDate = null;
             $calendarEvent = new Event(
                $name . ' <br> Status: ' . ucfirst($eventRepository->getStatus()),
                $eventStartDate,
                $eventEndDate,
            );
        }
        
        if(!empty($eventRepository->getService()->getColor())) {
            $color = $eventRepository->getService()->getColor();
            //var_dump($color);
            $calendarEvent->setOptions([
                'backgroundColor' => $color,
                'borderColor' => $color,
                'eventTextColor' => $color,
                'eventDisplay' => 'block',
            ]);
        } else {
            $calendarEvent->setOptions([
                'backgroundColor' => '#A4303F',
                'borderColor' => '#A4303F',
            ]);
        }

        if($this->configDataService->get('eventByTime') == 'YES') {
            $calendarEvent->setAllDay(false);
        }
        
        $calendarEvent->addOption(
            'url',
            $this->router->generate('app_event_show', [
                'id' => $eventRepository->getId(),
            ])
        );

        $calendar->addEvent($calendarEvent);
    }
}
```

}`

And in my webpack file (app.js) i have

```
     import { Calendar } ;
import dayGridPlugin ;
import timeGridPlugin ;
import listPlugin from ;
import allLocales from ;
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar-holder");

  let { eventsUrl } = calendarEl.dataset;

  let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    editable: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    height: "auto",
    locales: allLocales,
    locale: 'en',
    eventSources: [
      {
        url: eventsUrl,
        method: "POST",
        extraParams: {
          filters: JSON.stringify({}) // pass your parameters to the subscriber
        },
        failure: () => {
          // alert("There was an error while fetching FullCalendar!");
        },
      },
    ],
    
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek, listMonth"
    },
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    eventDisplay: "block",
    //displayEventTime: true,
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    plugins: [ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin ],
    timeZone: "UTC",
    eventContent: function(arg) {
      return {
        html: arg.event.title.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
      }
    },
  });
  let lang = calendarEl.dataset.lang;
  calendar.render();
  calendar.setOption('locale', lang);
});
```

So if i uncomment displayEventTime still is not working.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/displayEventTime

Comment: No, is not working, i know is there on full calendar  but this full calendar is a bundle for symfony - https://github.com/tattali/CalendarBundle

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. The same options are still available within fullCalendar. Just because it's bundled with other things doesn't cause any of its internal features to be removed. If you couldn't make it work, please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] of the issue showing exactly what you tried. That way we can help you find the exact solution for your specific situation. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. The "bundling" is actually just some `<script` tags in the HTML pointing to a CDN. So you can change them to whatever version of fullCalendar you want, without affecting anything else in the bundle. Since 4.1 is very out of date, if you are starting a new project I would strongly suggest upgrading to the latest version of fullCalendar (6.x) instead. It has more features, better performance, and fewer bugs.

Comment: I will edit the question because the bundle for symfony has a php code for allday, start, end and so on. You could add some option but there is no option for displayEventTime and is not working even if i put on script. The problem is on CalendarBundle.

Comment: Yes please do that. Because I don't know what you mean. Within `var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {` you can put any of the documented fullCalendar options. Symfony is only on your server-side, and has no influence on that JS code.

Comment: `a php code for allday, start, end`...ah. are you talking about event properties? Because `displayEventTime` is a calendar-wide property. It is not a property of a single event. The valid properties of individual events are listed in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-parsing, but `displayEventTime` is in the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-display section, which is one of the (many) lists of calendar-wide options you can set. There's an overview of all options here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4#toc

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I meant to suggest [displayEventEnd](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/displayEventEnd) instead. This is working, with front-end code based on yours - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/MWPxJym . Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Your `eventContent` code overwrites the HTML provided by fullCalendar and replaces it with nothing except the event's title.

If you're going to do that, then any other content you want to show in the event must also be reproduced in the string that your eventContent code generates.

```
eventContent: function (arg) {
  return {
    html: arg.event.start.toLocaleTimeString(undefined, { "hour": "numeric", "minute": "numeric"}) + ' ' + arg.event.title.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
  };
}
```

(You can of course adjust the time formatting to your requirements.)

Working demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxyNYJV

More info:

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString